# Searching and selecting data from a list of predefined words in Excel

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I am new to Excel but I have started to use it recently to clean datasets and hoping someone can help.

I have exported a list of twitter followers and would like to label them into groups in a separate column. Each line has handle, bio and URL. At the moment, I am using find and replace to search for a broad term at a time - for example 'architect' in each column, then I colour the cell to help me filter by colour allowing me to add a tag in my new column.

However this is taking ages. Is there a way that I could search the whole worksheet from a list I have? I would like to be able to search the url column from a list of know urls I have, and the bio column from a list of keywords I have.

I have attached a picture to illustrate - column to search on the left and list of keywords to search at the same time on the right. If I can simply highlight all the columns that include those words somehow I can colour and filter.

I have also not written any formulas in excel before so just a beginner, I have also tagged tableau in case there is a simpler way to do this there.

Thanks in advance to anyone who thinks they may be able to help :)

[image]

Comment: if all you want to do is color code cells with certain words then try condtional formatting.  you can specify both color and word and it finds them for you.  conditional formatting is on the home tab in the ribbon for excel 2013.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me - this only gives me the option for one word. Is there a way to do this from a list as a I have shown above? :)

Comment: yes, certainly.  you can set equal to the range, which will check the value in each cell to the values in your range.